# How to get contacts with hs_leads_status = Open from hubspot using Contact List API?

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-api

I want to get/pull all the contacts with hs_leads_status = Open and i am using `https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?count=100&property=phone&property=hs_lead_status&hs_lead_status=Open` but it returns hs_leads_status = Closed as well.
How to pass the parameters correctly and achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using the v1 API. You can however use the v3 API's search for this.
https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/search

Using an filter group with EQ param should satisfy your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Finally get succeeded with:

```
POST - https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search?

Body - {
    "properties": [
        "firstname",
        "lastname",
        "phone",
        "hs_lead_status"
    ],
    "limit": 100,
    "filterGroups": [
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "propertyName": "hs_lead_status",
                    "operator": "EQ",
                    "value": "Open"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but the limitation is that it returns only 100 records with pagination.